# Parent <ul> same height as child <ul>

Tags: css, navigation, html-lists, nav

I have some nested `<ul>`s and I want them to be the same height: the height of the tallest one. I cannot specify the height of any `<ul>` since it depends on the amount of `<li>`s in it.

I figure I could solve this pretty easy using some js, but I am curious if this could be fixed using CSS.

I created a simple fiddle to demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vnFLK/2/

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Li 1
            <ul>
                <li>Sub 1</li>
                <li>Sub 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Li 2
            <ul class="green">
                <li>Sub 1</li>
                <li>Sub 2</li>
                <li>Sub 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The `<ul>` with green borders is supposed to determine the height of the root `<ul>` and then I want the sibling `<ul>` to get the same height. The green `<ul>` is pushed 200% to the right just to be clearer.

This is a simplified representation of a navigation where a `<ul>` is a submenu that is going to be pulled over the parent one. Therefore they need to be the same height to prevent the parent menu being shown.

/Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely-positioned elements are no longer part of the document flow - they act as a new context. Therefore the parent element has no idea what size the child element is and cannot adjust its own size to match it.

There is no CSS solution for this. You need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to use relative and get rid of the placeholders?

Comment: No, anything you want on-screen that doesn't push other content around needs to use absolute positioning.

Comment: OK, thank you, I will try with some JavaScript then.